# "warning: field `somebool` is never read" for struct field only referenced in second, non-trait impl

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings, rust-cargo

This may be a feature I don't know yet.  I have this compiler message:

```
$ cargo build --lib
  Compiling secondimpl v0.1.0 (/home/nsdd/garage/sames/rustex/secondimpl)
 warning: field `somebool` is never read
 --> src/lib.rs:6:5
  |
5 | pub struct ExampleStruct {
  |            ------------- field in this struct
6 |     somebool: bool,
  |     ^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default

 warning: associated function `playhere` is never used
  --> src/lib.rs:31:8
   |
31 |     fn playhere(&self) -> usize {
   |        ^^^^^^^^

warning: `secondimpl` (lib) generated 2 warnings
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.16s
```

And this is my example code:

```
pub trait ExampleTrait {
    fn new(mynum: usize) -> Self;
}

pub struct ExampleStruct {
    somebool: bool,
    somenum: usize,
}

impl Default for ExampleStruct {
    fn default() -> Self {
        ExampleStruct {
            somebool: true,
            somenum: 999,
        }
    }
}

impl ExampleTrait for ExampleStruct {

    fn new(mynum: usize) -> Self {
        let mut buffer: ExampleStruct = Default::default();
        buffer.somenum = mynum;
        return buffer;
    }

}

impl ExampleStruct {

    fn playhere(&self) -> usize {
        if self.somebool {
            return self.somenum;
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

So because I only use `self.somenum` in the second impl, it seems, the compiler doesn't like it.  Presumably there is some declaration or syntax change I can make to stop this warning, as it's obviously a concern that is not taking the second impl into account.  The field is something that won't occur in other traits, so I cannot put it in the trait.

Comment: Sorry.  It simply goes away if the struct is pub.

Comment: Do you mean if the _field_ is `pub`?

Answer (score 3):

Rust considers what is used transitively. Yes, the field is read from `ExampleStruct::play_here()` but *this function is never called.* Because the function isn't called, it is irrelevant when deciding whether anything else in the program is used.

This applies even through multiple functions; if you add a non-public function that calls `ExampleStruct::play_here()` but you don't call *that* function anywhere, you would still get a warning; Rust determines that the entire call chain is dead code.

Note that there are exceptions:

- Anything declared `pub` is considered used, because those things are exported and *could* be used by other crates.  (This is mostly intended for library crates, but declaring something `pub` even in a binary crate causes the compiler to consider it "used.")
- Traits and their implementations are always considered to be used. (This could change later for non-public traits or for implementations of traits on non-public types where the implementation never gets used. There is [a related open feature request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50927).)

`ExampleStruct::play_here()` does not fall into either of these categories.